# How to run Intel XDK on my system (Windows 8 64 bit)?

Tags: android, html, cross-platform, mobile-website, intel-xdk

This app always hangs up on startup showing the "initializing" window and nothing happen.I had uninstall and reinstall the latest version several times but probem was not solved. I downloaded node-webkit files compatible with my system and replaced the original files as answered on other questions here on stackoverflow but still same problem. I am trying everything which I found on internet to solve this issue but I am not succeed till now.

Comment: Super User would be a better place for this. This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

We have the XDK running on many Windows 8 and 8.1 (and 7) machines that are nearly all 64-bit. I have two 64-bit Windows 8.1 machines that I am using with no troubles.

Do not try to replace the node.js that is part of the app, that will raise havoc.

See [this post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/542074) for how to completely wipe the XDK off your system and then download and install fresh. My suspicion is you either had some bad cache files left from a prior install or you're having some network (either bad connection or proxy) issues that are getting in the way.

Another thing that could be causing trouble is something in your project or the project.xdk file that is in the top directory of your project causing troubles. If you delete the global-settings.xdk file (rather than saving it, as the cleanup instructions direct you to), it will cause you to start with no projects. Then try to create a new project from a template or demo. If that all works, then try to open your existing project.